# How to access Alfresco database via url?

Tags: database, alfresco

in my alfresco-global.properties file it says:

```
 db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
```

I want to know how to access this database in the browser?

Comment: How you would any other PostGreSQL database?

Comment: I don't understand, the alfresco app i have uses postgresSQL

Answer (score 1):

To connect to alfresco data base you can use any Postgresql client, by the way, alfresco install pgAdmin client.

To use this client you shoud open `{alfresco_install_directory}/postgresql/bin/pgAdmin3`, add new server and type database credentials(host, port ...) from `alfresco-global.properties`.

**Edit**

This is an example of configuration, you can find all what you need in `alfresco-global.properties`.

[image]

Comment: thanks
can you please tell me what to put in each credentials?

Comment: I mean what to put in name, host, and service ?

Comment: @KaderMoulayEly thanks to vote and accept the answer if it's helpful

Answer (score 1):

The default PostgreSQL client application is [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html). If you can't install this or if you want to use a GUI client, the PostgreSQL community maintains [a list of GUI clients](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools).

Every client either asks you for credentials or will present you a form where you can enter them.

The JDBC URL from your question is

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}
```

My guess is that `db.name` is equal to `alfresco`. So the complete JDBC URL would be

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco
```

If you have installed Alfresco only your local computer, this would be the JDBC URL to use with a client that uses JDBC. If you have installed Alfresco on a different computer, you would have to replace `localhost` with the host name of this computer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have made the default installation(postgresql), you cant.
If you have switched the database to mysql you could use something like php admin or similar. Hope it helps.